# Should i pass functions to my component manually or using ref attribute?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, design-patterns

I have built my own `FormBuilder` component (which is almost `5k` line now), so it can cover all my needs, one issue i'm encountering is loading a new set of `FormData` any time the user needs, since my `FormBuilder` can accept a set of nested components, its kinda hard comparing the changes, and handling everything in component did mount, one easy way is building a `loadFormData` method inside the `FormBuilder` and calling this method from outside the component
I know this can easily be accomplished using `ref attribute`, but react highly suggest avoiding this and i got discouraged! and i was not sure if i should do this or not!
So i came up with a new alternative which kinda does the same thing:

```
class A {

    onGetFormBuilderInternalFunction = (functions) => {
        this.formBuilderFunctions = functions
    }

    onLoadButtonClick = () => {        
      this.formBuilderFunctions.loadFormData(someNewData)
    }

    render () {
        <FormBuilder onGetInternalFunction={this.onGetFormBuilderInternalFunction}
    }
}


class FormBuilder {
    componentDidMount() {
        if (this.props.onGetInternalFunction) {
            this.props.onGetInternalFunction({
                loadFormData: this.loadFormData,
            })
        }
    }
}
```

So what do you think ?, is this a better approach ? or is this still a bad one ?, i was thinking using this method will at least only gives access to functions i need and not everything else.
I should also mention, `loadFormData` is simply one example, and there are at least a couple of these `special function` which i really really think is best to simply call from outside, so even if i do somehow pass the new data from props and handle it in `componentDidUpdate`, for the rest of these functions, i still need to access the `FormBuilder`

Comment: Wouldn't you rather re-mount the `FormBuilder` component when a new set of data comes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how your component is set up so these are just thoughts based on a vague understanding.

Generally, you wouldn't want to do either of those approaches. Instead, the recommended approach is to pass `someNewData` to `FormBuilder` as one or more props (I'm guessing one prop, in your case).

> Avoid using refs for anything that can be done declaratively.
>
> – React Docs: [When to Use Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#when-to-use-refs)

This sort of scenario is discussed in [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html):

> Instead of trying to sync the state between different components, you should rely on the top-down data flow.
>
> – React Docs: [Lifting State Up # Lessons Learned](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html#lessons-learned)

If you're keeping track of changed state separate from your initial data, then you just need to reset that state when the form data (`someNewData`) changes. However, that's not the recommended approach.

Instead, uncontrolled components might be a great fit. By setting `defaultValue` to the initial data (i.e. `someNewData.someField`) and then letting the component deal with the value until you need it (e.g. when submit is clicked read the value from the component), you might be able to simplify your `FormBuilder`. Note: if you want to reset the uncontrolled component when your initial data (`someNewData.someField`) changes, you will need to use a `key` prop on the uncontrolled component with the value based `someNewData.someField`.

> If you want to “reset” some state when a prop changes, consider either making a component [fully controlled](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-controlled-component) or [fully uncontrolled with a key](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-uncontrolled-component-with-a-key) instead.
>
> – React Docs: [React Component # static getDerivedStateFromProps()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops)

Comment: I choose your answer but gave the bounty to the answer which was most close to my bounty request, but i will consider your solutions and see if i can fit my `FormBuilder` in any of them, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Yes that is the correct way to do it. However, if you have a 5,000 line component I would strongly suggest breaking it up into smaller sub components.

Answer (score 3):

Keep state and handler functions in Parent and pass it down to FormBuilder as props.

Comment: i'm talking about a 5000 line `FormBuilder` here, plus i have other conditions too which makes it impossible for me to do this.

Answer (score 2):

In response to your main question:

> Better as you are doing right now than using ref.

I base this answer on what the react documentation says in the last paragraph of the ["ref" glossary description](https://reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#refs) and that the current approach can also be supported in case `FormBuilder` is refactored to be a functional component in the future (with Hooks and so), while using "ref" wouldn't.